# Server end point URL restriction for WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a `WCF` service with multiple operation contract and the service will run in multiple data centers.

I want to restrict (not allow to call) some operation contract in some data center.

Could someone please help me to achieve my requirement?

Comment: you can implement authorization for that.

Answer (score 0):

If i did not misunderstand your service will run on different machines(Each machine has its own web.config file) ? So you can group your operation contracts in different service contracts and then edit your web.config files for allowing these service contracts.

Edit: 
Let's say you have OperationA,B and C

```
[ServiceContract]
public class ABCService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public Message OperationA()

    [OperationContract]
    public Message OperationB()

   [OperationContract]
    public Message OperationC()
}

[ServiceContract]
public class ABService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public Message OperationA()

    [OperationContract]
    public Message OperationB()
}
```

If one machine shuold access only OperationA and OperationB use this

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ABService"/>
```

If one machien should acces all operation use this

```
<endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ABCService"/>
```

Comment: could you please explain some more?

Comment: I have edited, my approach could be very wrong because i did not try it before, just idea :p.

Comment: So you presume OP has multiple contracts.

Comment: yes, grouping  operation contracts according to needs